# A functional programming language with a higher-order function similar to Haskell's flip but uncurried

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

Is there any functional programming language whose functions are not automatically curried, which has a built-in or library higher-order function that takes a function of the form (AxB)->C and returns an equivalent function of the form (BxA)->C? This is similar to Haskell's flip function.

Comment: Such questions are [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please consider asking over there at [`r/programming`](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming).

Comment: @kostix: I will ask at r/programming, though I don't see what's off-topic about my question. Can you please let me know, so I will avoid asking off-topic questions in the future?

Comment: Point 4 in the section titled "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:" at that "what is on-topic" document. May also be point 5. The general idea is that SO is for narrowly-scoped technical problems. They may be with using a programming language or a tool related to software development but they still have to be narrowly scoped and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ["Homotopy Type Theory"](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1174-g29279f5.pdf) in 1.4 on page 26 the function for the curried version is called **"swap"**:

```
swap: Π(A:U)Π(B:U)Π(C:U) (A -> B -> C) -> (B -> A -> C)

swap(A, B, C, g)(b, a) := λb.λa.g(a)(b)
```

I don't know why you would want to have a separate name for the uncurried version, what's the difference anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need currying to implement `flip`.  Here's an implementation in Scala:

```scala
def flip[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): (B, A) => C = (b: B, a: A) => f(a, b)
```

Whether it's "built in" is another question.  In functional programming that isn't as important.  It's also not as useful without currying, as usually you want to use `flip` in order to make composition work.

Comment: Thanks. However, the point of the question was precisely to find a built-in or standard-library implementation of such an operator, because I'm looking for a *standard name* for this operator. I don't want to make up a name for this operator, if one is already in common use.

Comment: @EvanAad what's wrong with "flip"? `flip(f)(y,x) = f(x,y)`. the language is non-curried, the args are still flipped.

Comment: @WillNess: I'd like to distinguish between the curried and the uncurried flip functions.

Comment: @EvanAad so it is the function that's uncurried, not the language? it's even simpler then: the answer is Haskell's `uncurry flip`.

Comment: @WillNess: I like 'swap' and 'flip' better.